# Can't Update sofware in Mint 18

Tags: apt

I'm running Mint 18 and all of a sudden I can't do a software update. I get the following error message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/util-linux/bsdutils_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
```

When I run `apt-get update` I get the following result:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for jim:
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Any suggestion on how to correct this is most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Have you done an `apt-get update` first, and 2. What reason does it give for the failure?

Comment: Just tried and here is what I got:

Comment: jim@jim-HP-Pavilion-dm4-Notebook-PC ~ $ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for jim: 
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
jim@jim-HP-Pavilion-dm4-Notebook-PC ~ $

Comment: I'll do it for you this time but please update your question with new information. If you put it here in the comments it can get lost or even simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably already running a software update (maybe a different application, maybe in a different window).

An alternative is that your filesystem containing `/var/lib/apt/lists` has detected a serious error and dropped into read-only mode. It's most likely that it's just the former, though.

Solution? Don't run two package management tools at the same time.

Comment: Thanks to all for your comments. This morning I opened Mint 18, clicked the Update Manager, and all the updates installed. Don't know how or why it started working again, but glad it did.

Comment: @slimjim my first sentence tells you (almost certainly) why it wasn't working for you.